# Using widgets with functions in Julia

Tags: julia, reactive-programming

I'm trying to have an input widget (Int slider in a Jupyter notebook) feed into a function and want the results of that function to update with corresponding changes in the input widget.

something like this:

```
using Interact, Reactive

function coolfunc(n)
  y = n + 10
  println("y is $y")
end

@manipulate for n in slider(1:8)
    coolfunc(n)
end
```

The function should print the value of Y for changes in int_range

Is this possible?

**update:**

So, it seems my issue is with the println() function. Does println() not work with the @manipulate macro?

for instance the below code produces the desired result:

```
function coolfunc(n)
    y = n + 10
    return y
end

@manipulate for x in slider(1:8)
    coolfunc(x)
end
```

I want to also be able to use the println() function and have it update with each run.

Comment: If you drop the `println` and just return `"y is $y"` you get the output widget updated.

Comment: Well, if you aren't tied to Jupyter, you can use `GtkInteract`. There `println` will write to the console. You could also use the `Interact` widgets directly and update the value. I think there is a label widget you could use.

Comment: You can also use [`Escher.jl`](http://escher-jl.org/), see [`examples/vectorgraphics.jl`](https://github.com/shashi/Escher.jl/blob/master/examples/vectorgraphics.jl)